# Java handle URL with special characters

Tags: java, android, webview, android-webview

Hi I'm currently using appcelerators Titanium, so far so good except I'm have great difficulty with downloading from urls with special characters typically square brackets.

The app receives information from an RSS feed which has a url with special characters, i used yahoo pipes and regex to replace these with %5B & %5D which worked fine but that url is then redirected to  the actual download url which also has square brackets which leaves me with an error illegal character

can anyone advise on how to handle special characters in url

thanks

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html

Comment: It works for strict URL encoding of the individual parts as well. You can also use gauva's UrlEscapers http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v17.0/javadoc/com/google/common/net/UrlEscapers.html

Comment: [`Uri.encode()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#encode%28java.lang.String%29) is probably suited here.

Comment: hi thanks someone told me to var url = Ti.Network.encodeURIComponent(context.userInfo.link); but now I'm getting the error [WARN] :   Uri: Error parsing port string.
[WARN] :   Uri: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: //xxxx.com but its not showing the http: